# Relay support to GraphQL Unions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I'm having a trouble when using React JS combined with Relay JS and GraphQL, where it keeps getting the same error message, despite the fact that the query to GraphQL works. Everything worked fine until the moment when we decided to use Unions from GraphQl. Now I can get the data from GraphQl but it keeps getting an error.

I make this query:

```
query {
  node(id: "value"){
    ... on Node {
      ... on User {
        name
        email
        domain {
          ... on Domain {
            users(first: 100){
              edges{
                node{
                  ... on User{
                    name
                    email
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is suposed to receive an object from the API that is an union

```
UserOrErrorsUnion {
 User{
  name
  email
  ...
 }
 ErrorSet{
  errors
 }
}
```

The react component code is the following:

```
export class LoggedConnect {
...
}

export default translate(['common', 'root'], { wait: true })(
  Relay.createContainer(LoggedConnect, {
    fragments: {
      user: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on UserOrErrorsUnion {
        ... on User {
          name
          id
          email
        }
      }
      `,
    },
  })
);
```

The error is this one:

> (program):36 Warning: RelayReadyState: Invalid state change from `{"aborted":false,"done":false,"error":{},"events":[{"type":"NETWORK_QUERY_START"},{"type":"CACHE_RESTORE_START"},{"type":"CACHE_RESTORE_FAILED"},{"type":"NETWORK_QUERY_ERROR","error":{}}],"ready":false,"stale":false}` to `{"error":{}}`.

I think that is because relay receives two objects and don't know how to handle them, so the state becomes inconsistent

Comment: If you post your Schema from the API I will have a look.